# How to call the tap on the back-button for other app in android

Tags: android

I have an android java app that can launch other applications(example: Google Chrome).
Is there a way to programmatically call the "tap on the back-button" from my own app to the opened app. For example, if the users launches Google Chrome from my app, at one point, I want to call the "tap on the back-button" for the Google Chrome app, as the user itself tapped the back button from the Chrome app?

Thank you!

Later edit for clarification(hopefully):

My app is starting a service. After the user opens my app(at that point the service starts), he then opens another app named X(it can be any app from google play). In my service, at one point, I want to trigger the back button action for the X app, like "calling the onBackPreesd() method" of the foreground activity for the X app, as if the user pressed the back button while app X was in foreground.

Also, at one point the service for my app is calling the following method: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/input keyevent 4 ");, which executes the onBackPressed() method for the foreground activity of my own app. Can I do something similar for the X app that the user has opened? My app is always aware of the other apps that the user had opened.

Thank you!

Comment: you want to override onBackPressed for opened application in your application?

Comment: no, I simply want to do what the opened app does when the user press the back button while the opened app is in the foreground. In my example with the chrome app, I want to send the user to the previous web page (what chrome does when the user press the back button). That is just an example, but I want to implement a general behavior for all the apps that my app can open.  In simple words, I want to "call the  onBackPressed method" of the opened app.

Comment: You cannot programmatically initiate a back button when your app is not in the foreground. Imagine how bewitching such a behavior would appear to a user. You don't know what app they are using and a back press would be rather disruptive. I don't see why you would need this functionality, are you trying to reopen your app?

Answer (score 1):

Great Raz! one way to open other links in your app by intent action **" but there is no way to open your app from another app when the activity of your main app is destroyed"**
this will help you to open any activity link in your own app

try to add this code in manifest

```
<activity
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher"
 android:name=".features.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:host="mysitename.com"
              android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

your question is not clear but if this is not helpful for you you can go with Click here [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher)

Comment: Hello and thank you for your time. I will try to explain it better: My app is starting a service. After the user opens my app(at that point the service starts), he then opens another app named X(it can be any app from google play). In my service, at one point, i want to trigger the back button action for the X app, like "calling the onBackPreesd() method" of the foreground activity for the X app, as if the user pressed the back button while app X was in foreground.

Comment: also, at one point the service for my app is calling the following method:  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/input keyevent 4 ");, which executes the onBackPressed() method for foreground activity of my own app. Can i do something similar foe the X app that the user has opened?